# Change picture caption with corresponding onclicked image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, onclick

I have made a gallery page that has thumbnail images, and when clicked, the image will be shown on the main viewer above (this I have working). Under the main viewer, a caption is shown. However I would like it so that the caption changes depending on the image, what can i add to the javascript and HTML to achieve this?

E.g. Thumbnail 1 is clicked, image viewer displays image 1, caption displays caption 1.

Then thumbnail 2 is clicked, image viewer displays image 2, caption displays caption 2 etc.

HTML

```
<div class="containermain">
<img id="img-main" alt="main image" src="images/placeholder.png" />

<div id="myCaption">Caption</div>

<div class="containerimg">
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image1" data-fullsize="images/image1.jpg" src="thumb/image1.jpg" />
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image2" data-fullsize="images/image2.jpg" src="thumb/image2.jpg" />
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image3" data-fullsize="images/image3.jpg" src="thumb/image3.jpg" />
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image4" data-fullsize="images/image4.jpg" src="thumb/image4.jpg" />
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image5" data-fullsize="images/image5.jpg" src="thumb/image5.jpg" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("img.img" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        var newSrc= $(this).data("fullsize");          
        $("#img-main").attr("src", newSrc);
    });
});
```

Comment: What are caption 1, caption 2, etc. Coming from, what are the values supposed to be?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek This is what I am not too sure of, being relatively new to javascript and all. Hence this post, was hoping someone could aid me on this

Comment: How would I know what the values should be? Is it the images `alt` or `src`, or some value that you need to define yourself?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek the alt value is what I had in mind sorry

Comment: That's fine, I'm just hesitant on answering until I know for sure what you are looking for. I was assuming it might be the `alt` but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `$('#myCaption').text($(this).attr("alt"))` to assign the value of the clicked image's `alt` attribute to your captions text.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("img.img" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        var newSrc= $(this).data("fullsize");          
        $("#img-main").attr("src", newSrc);
        $('#myCaption').text($(this).attr("alt"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containermain">
<img id="img-main" alt="main image" src="images/placeholder.png" />

<div id="myCaption">Caption</div>

<div class="containerimg">
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image1"  data-fullsize="images/image1.jpg" src="thumb/image1.jpg" />
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image2"  data-fullsize="images/image2.jpg" src="thumb/image2.jpg" />
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image3"  data-fullsize="images/image3.jpg" src="thumb/image3.jpg" />
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image4"  data-fullsize="images/image4.jpg" src="thumb/image4.jpg" />
<img class="img" alt="thumbnail-image5"  data-fullsize="images/image5.jpg" src="thumb/image5.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine, thank you for the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
    $('img').click(function(){
        var alt = $(this).attr("alt")
        alert(alt)
    });
```